# MySQL Not Adding To Database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5

I have a form to signup with the code below:

```
<form method="post">
Username<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="16" name="username"><br />
Password<input type="password" size="12" maxlength="32" name="password"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" />
</form>
```

And then I have it too check if the username contains any special characters and if it doesn't it runs this code:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "will");
define("DB_PASS", "blahblah");
define("DB_NAME", "blahblah");
define("TBL_USERS", "users");

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

function addNewUser($username, $password){
   global $connection;
   $username =$POST['username'];
   $password =$_POST['password'];
   $password1 = md5($password);
   $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
   return mysql_query($q, $connection);
}
```

This should add the username and password to my table with the password as an md5 hash but it doesn't, could someone please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: First the mandatory [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327). But in all seriousness, I really recommend that you read [this article](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-security) for some knowledge in PHP security pitfalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:
Don't use concatenated strings to insert values to the database. This is a major security hole, it can be exploited using a technique called SQL-Injection. You can prevent this by using so called [Prepared Statements](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm).

And this should solve your problem:
You probably don't really call the addNewUser function. You just connect ot the database.

Try this:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "will");
define("DB_PASS", "blahblah");
define("DB_NAME", "blahblah");
define("TBL_USERS", "users");

function addNewUser($username, $password){
   global $connection;
   $password1 = md5($password);
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
   return mysql_query($q, $connection);
}    

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
addNewUser($_POST["text"], $_POST["password"]);
```

Comment: how would I stop SQL Injection then?

Comment: Hey, and rate me up if you liked my answer!

Comment: @Falcon Please see my login post because I'm really stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually calling `addNewUser` here. Also, as a future hint, using prepared statements to avoid SQL injections is probably the way to go for anything but the most trivial of applications. One tutorial on using SQL prepared statements in PHP is [here](http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the `addNewUser` function?

**Also, watch your SQL-Statement for [SQL-Injections](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection).**

Answer (score 0):

$username =$POST['username'] is wrong. You forgot _ . It must be $username = $_POST['username'].

Answer (score 0):

To be ultra clear...

You have a function in there, but it's never called, as everyone has said.

To call it, Add this line before your function starts:

```
$var = addNewUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
```

**EDIT:**
Further...
In your function, you already have $username and $password, you can delete these lines:

```
$username =$POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
```

And last but not least, storing your password with only md5 is not good practice.  Read up: http://elbertf.com/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/